# "Cut" the string on HTML

Tags: html, smarty

For my HTML, I use a smarty variable;

```html
 <div class="ty-blog__date">{$subpage.timestamp|date_format:"`$settings.Appearance.date_format`"}</div>
```

{$subpage.timestamp|date_format:"`$settings.Appearance.date_format`"} On compilation, the date appears as: Авг 17, 2016
Where: Авг - month, 17 - date, 2016 - year. However, it is a single string. 
I want to slice this string into consecutive parts in order to display each part as a separate HTML element.
An example:

```html
<span>month</span><span>date</span><span>year</span>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <span>{$subpage.timestamp|date_format:"%B"}</span><span>{$subpage.timestamp|date_format:"%e"}</span><span>{$subpage.timestamp|date_format:"%Y"}</span>
```

Comment: No problem at all. Be sure to remember my help, and some time (when you have the opportunity) be sure to pay it forward; help someone else whenever you can. That's the purpose of this place - to teach, be taught, and further learning.